# NullPointerException error in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm making a class involving objects. I'm having trouble with the retrieveMessage method, because when I test it, it returns a NullPointerException.

```
public class PostOffice 
   {
      public PostOffice(int size)
      {
         boxbox = new Letter[size];
      }
      public boolean placeLetter(Letter mail, int boxNum)
      {
         if(((boxNum>(boxbox.length-1))||(boxNum<0))||(boxbox[boxNum]!=null))
            return false;
         else{
            boxbox[boxNum]=mail;
            return true;
         }
      }
   /**Returns the message contained within the Letter located in the specific box number.
    * Returns "Empty!" if the post office box specified by the integer does not contain a Letter.
    * Returns "Box does not exist!" if there is no box with the specified integer.
    * @param boxNum The post office box number to be checked.
    */
      public String retrieveMsg(int boxNum)
      {
            if(boxNum<=boxbox.length-1)
            {
                String swag = boxbox[boxNum].getMsg();
                if(swag!=null && swag.isEmpty()==false)
                {
                    return swag;
                }
                return "Empty!";
            }
            return "Box does not exist!";
        }
      public Letter findSender(String name)
      {
         String sender;
         int index =0;
         for(int i = 0; i<boxbox.length; i++)
         {
            if((boxbox[i].getSender()).equals(name)){
               index= i;
            }
            else{
               return null;
            }
         }
         return boxbox[index];
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please post your stack trace.

Comment: What's null? Where's your stack trace? Tell us which line it appears on?

Comment: NullPointerException is probably the easiest of all Java exceptions to debug.  Learn how to debug.  Start by actually reading the exception information you get.

Comment: Tyy changing if(boxNum<=boxbox.length-1) into if(boxNum<=boxbox.length-1 && boxbox[boxNum]!=null)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the NullPointerException is thrown on this line :

```
String swag = boxbox[boxNum].getMsg();
```

When created, `boxbox` have *size* values, all of them are null.

You should first check if `boxbox[boxNum]` is null or not. If it is, it means that the post box does not contain a letter.